# How to create a HTML table with a custom number of columns in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm familiar with Powershell but have just learned how to convert to HTML to create reports. I have an array with one property that holds a lot of objects. When converting to HTML, instead of creating just one column that runs down the page with all the objects, I want to create 3 or 4 columns and spread the objects across the columns.

I know Powershell automatically creates the tables based on the object properties so not sure how to proceed and Google doesn't yield any helpful info.

TIA.

Comment: As far as I know there is no built-in cmdlet for doing this.  You can search through https://www.powershellgallery.com for html modules that might do this for you or consider writing your own.

Comment: Would doing `$array[0] | ConvertTo-Html` not work? Seems to work for me fairly well. Give it a try and report back with any problems in your code.

Comment: @Drew, the OP states that they would like to create a table with the objects spread across multiple columns, not a single column table which is what `ConvertTo-Html` will produce if you pipe an array of objects with only 1 property to it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.